# GUI crashes when connecting to FTP (java)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, ftp

I wrote a java program that connects to an FTP server, and displays a list of the content of the present working directory on the server. The code is as follows:

```
        public static void connect (){

        ftp = new FTPClient();
        FTPClientConfig config = new FTPClientConfig();
        ftp.configure(config);
        boolean error = false;

    try {
          ftp.connect(ftpConnect);
          ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
          ftp.login(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
          System.out.println("Connected to " + ftpConnect); 
          System.out.println("Server Reply Code: "+ftp.getReplyString());
          getFileData();
          ftp.disconnect();

    } catch(IOException e) {
          error = true;
          e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
          if(ftp.isConnected()) {
            try {
              ftp.disconnect();
            } catch(IOException ioe) {
              // do nothing
            }
          }
          System.exit(error ? 1 : 0);
        }
    }

    public static void getFileData(){
        try {
            fileFTP = ftp.listNames();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }      
    }

    public static void downloadFTPFile(final String source, String newFileName) {
        File checker = new File(source);
        if(checker.exists()){
            System.out.println("File \" "+source+"\"  already exists. Canceling donwload...");
            System.exit(1);

        } else {        
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFileName)) {    
                System.out.println("Downloading "+source+". This might take a while...");
                System.out.println("Go make yourself a cup of coffee. Or two...");


                ftp.retrieveFile(source, fos);
                System.out.println("Done!");  

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }    
            }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        connect();

    }   

}
```

I got a redirect class that prints all Sysout actions to a TextArea in my swing GUI. However, when I launch the FTP connection in my GUI, the GUI itself disappears, like if it crashes, but on my console all the output is shown correctly, but not on the redirect. Through the GUI, I also have other functions that are called, like an unzipper, and for every other function the GUI works perfectly fine and displays all the SysOut stuff in my textArea. Is this some sort of incompatibility between the FTPClient stuff?

cheers

Comment: run your GUI through command line and see if it throws some sort of exceptions in there

Comment: I just did - I get " package org.apache.commons.net.ftp does not exist
" HOWEVER that is inacurate, since I imported the org.apache.commons.net jar into my project and bound it o my build path correctly. It works too on the console output ! just not in the sysout redirect...

Comment: can you add how you redirect your sysout?

Answer (score 1):

take this as a long comment not a full answer:

try to believe that exceptions are your friends not enemy and its almost certainly your making the mistake not the compiler :).

1. did you run the program on console without GUI? if so track down exactly what packages you've used (sometimes different versions of packages may corrupt your program.
2. open the relevant .jar file and ensure that it definitely contains  `org.apache.commons.net.ftp`.
3. check out .jar file versions.

Comment: 1: I compiled and ran the programm through the terminal, that's wehre the error comes from; 2: org.apache.commons.net.ftp is indeed in the .jar file I added to the build path; 3: the jar I have is version 3.3...

Comment: @SpadeJohnsson did you check that you don't have any other version of the package? e.g. version 3.2...

Comment: @SpadeJohnsson open ur jar file, check the libraries it uses.